# How secure EC2 Instance (Windows Server 2016) after opening port 8080

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I have very little experience working with AWS. So I read through all question on Stackoverflow but couldn't find the answer, hence I am asking this question.

I have setup an EC2 instance (Windows Server 2016). While setting up the instance at Configure Security Group the settings that I used are as follows:

[image]

For RDP I think I should put my IP, so that only I can access the Windows Server from my IP. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

In my Windows Server 2016, I have installed Tomcat which runs on port 8080 and in firewall settings I have created an inbound rule for port 8080 as well. Therefore as shown in above screenshot I have kept port 8080 open for all. Is this correct? I am not sure what I should put as Source for port 8080.

Finally when things are setup correctly, I am able to access my tomcat homepage from Windows Server 2016 (localhost:8080) and also from external machine i.e. (EC2 public IP :8080)

The crux of the problem is when I leave these settings as is, somehow my Windows Server 2016 gets infected by Viruses and Trojans. I have to run Windows Defender to get rid of them but despite that every 2-3 days I still see viruses on my Windows Server 2016.

How can I secure my EC2 Instance Windows Server 2016 so that it does not get infected by viruses? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you wish to connect to Tomcat running on port 8080? Do you wish it to be only accessible to apps on the same computer, or from a different EC2 instance, or from a computer on the Internet?

Comment: @John Thank you for replying. Yes, I wish to connect to Tomcat on port 8080. This is an Android app and I wish it to be accessible from smartphone anywhere. My app is already placed on playstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want the Tomcat server to be accessible from many devices on the Internet. Therefore, your configuration is correct since it is opening port 8080 to anyone on the Internet.

It is unlikely that opening this port causes your instance to be "infected by Viruses and Trojans", since it is only your application that is being exposed. You'd need some very bad Tomcat configurations to expose your system to viruses.

If you do think this opening the port exposes you to such threats, you should examine your **Tomcat logs** to see what types of requests are coming in that might be impacting your application in unexpected ways.